# Mounting LUN in AIX

Tags: aix, storage

I have LUN created and added to AIX, I know this because once I created the LUN and the name I gave in the IBM storage is displayed and also I used the following commands

```
chdev -l hdisk7 -a pv=yes
```

then

```
cfgmgr -i disk
```

Now when I type lspv i can see the hdisk7 fully initialized. But the question now is how to mount this to a folder?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mount disks in AIX, nor do you create folders.  AIX uses Logical Volume Manager for storage.

You need to add the disk to a volume group (a new one, or an existing one).  Once in a volume group, the space on the disk is free to be used by new or existing Logical Volumes.

Once you've got Logical Volumes you can create Filesystems (unless you need raw LV's).

For Volume Groups, look at `mkvg` and `extendvg`.  For Logical Volumes, look at `mklv` and `extendlv`.  For Filesystems, look at `crfs` and `chfs`.

In your case, to create a new volume group (called newvg),

`mkvg -y newvg hdisk7`

or add the disk to an existing volume group (called oldvg),

`extendvg oldvg hdisk7`

From this point, all of your commands focus on the volume group, and not necessarily the disk.

To create a new logical volume (called newlv in the newvg volume group) of 10 partitions,

`mklv -y newlv newvg 10`

or optionally,

`mklv -y newlv newvg 10 hdisk7` (this will force it onto new disk).

Or, to extend an existing logical volume (called oldlv) by 10 partitions over the new disk,

`extendlv oldlv 10 hdisk7`

And then finally, to create a filesystem,

`crfs -v jfs2 -d /dev/newlv -m /your/new/directory`

Commands are from memory - check the man pages for all of them.